# setting up terraform v0.14.0 on Apple M1

Tags: terraform, apple-m1, terraform-provider-azure, darwin

Any pointers how to setup Terraform v0.14.0 on a Apple M1 , as tfenv doesn't support v0.14.0 on Apple M1

```
tfenv install v0.14.0
Installing Terraform v0.14.0
Downloading release tarball from https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.14.0/terraform_0.14.0_darwin_arm64.zip
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403

Tarball download failed
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using `tfenv`, you can override the architecture with `TFENV_ARCH` environment variables: `TFENV_ARCH=amd64`. See [docs](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv#environment-variables).

If you are not using `tfenv`:

Terraform is a simple executable, you can download it and unzip it from here:
https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.14.0/:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.14.0/terraform_0.14.0_darwin_amd64.zip

unzip terraform_0.14.0_darwin_amd64.zip
```

Please note, there is no `arm64` build for osx, but the `amd64` works just fine on a Mac M1.

Now you can copy the extracted executable in a folder like `/usr/local/bin`, which should be on your `PATH`, so you can run `terraform` command from anywhere in your system.

Comment: I want to use 0.13 and it works just fine by changing the version number. Thx!

Answer (score 38):

You can set the env var TFENV_ARCH and use tfenv

```
TFENV_ARCH=amd64 tfenv install 0.14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**tfswitch** You switch between different versions of terraform :  https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

---

Hello! Setting up Terraform v0.14.0 on an Apple M1 machine can be smoothly done using one of the two following methods: Both of these methods leverage the power of version managers, allowing you to easily switch between different Terraform versions without much hassle.

#### Option 1: Using tfswitch

The `tfswitch` tool is a handy utility that allows you to switch between different Terraform versions easily. If you haven't already installed it on your machine, you can do so using Homebrew. Once installed, switching to Terraform version 0.14.0 is a straightforward process.

```bash
# Install tfswitch if you haven't done so.
brew install warrensbox/tap/tfswitch

# Switch to Terraform version 0.14.0
tfswitch 0.14.0
```

This command will download and switch your Terraform to version 0.14.0, making it the active version for your projects.

#### Option 2: Using tfenv

Another excellent tool for managing Terraform versions is `tfenv`. It's similar to `tfswitch` but specifically tailored for Terraform. Installing `tfenv` and then using it to install a specific Terraform version is also quite simple.

```bash
# Install tfenv if you haven't already
brew install tfenv

# Install and use Terraform version 0.14.0.
tfenv install 0.14.0
```

**Note:** It seems there might be a typo in your original script under Option 2, where it says `tfenv install 0.7.0`. Assuming you're aiming for Terraform version 0.14.0, you should use `tfenv install 0.14.0` as shown above.

Both methods are efficient for managing different versions of Terraform on your machine, especially on an Apple M1, ensuring you can work on various projects that may require different versions. Pick the one that best suits your workflow, or feel free to have both at your disposal for greater flexibility.